# Move to vs Move over to

Tags: prepositions, difference

What is the difference between the use of prepositions in the following sentences:

- Recently Helen Keller moved to a new apartment.
- Peter Pan moved over to a new home.

And

- Linda Hamilton moved in to live with her parents.
- James Cameron moved into another house.

Comment: There's no "in" or "at" in your examples.

Comment: @Peter Sorry. I found the explanation for "at" with move, and added the "in".. but since I know only the idiom 'to move in" can it be used in such a way?

Comment: What do you think these phrases mean? I can move from a chair to the sofa, or I can move from an apartment into a house. Just asking us to differentiate between short phrases without any context or intended meaning is a rather fruitless exercise. And please remember that when you ask future questions, too. You’ve asked six dozen by now; I’d expect some improvement over time.

Comment: @J.R. You are really strange. I'm asking serious questions that you simply cannot understand. I've given context. Notice how Peter understood me plainly and gave a good answer that I find very easy to understand.

Comment: Sovereign -  I understand this: many words in English are quite flexible and can be used in many different ways. And more than once I’ve spent time composing an answer only to be told by the O.P., “No, I didn’t mean that, I meant something else instead" – something that could have been made clear with just an extra example. Peter may have gotten it right, but that’s partly luck. Your original example: _To move to a new place_ has **many** valid interpretations. I can move a knickknack to a new place on the shelf; my company can move to a new place on the other side of town.

Comment: As a footnote, take a look at some of your questions that received [many upvotes](http://ell.stackexchange.com/users/44134/sovereignsun?tab=questions&sort=votes), and compare them to your questions that [weren’t upvoted](http://ell.stackexchange.com/users/44134/sovereignsun?tab=questions&sort=votes&page=3). I don’t think I’m the only one in this community who values and appreciates a little extra effort put into a question.

Comment: @J.R. I agree. Look at the two examples you've given: *I can move a knickknack to a new place on the shelf*; *my company can move to a new place on the other side of town.* Both as Peter answered carry one meaning. They both mean *simply to change location from one place to another.* And the different between the prepositions in this case would certainly be a common one for other examples of a kind. Doesn't in this case **move over** imply just an emphatic way of saying the same? And how would a change from *to* to *in/into* inflict the meaning?

Comment: There are subtle differences in preposition use, but, unfortunately, you question doesn’t ask about that, so I’m not going to delve into the matter in my comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To move **to** a new place.

is simply to change location from one place to another.

> To move **over** to a new place.

"over" is usually used when a contrast is emphasized

> We **moved over** from the west side to the east side of town.
>   We just **moved over** from the UK.
>
> To **move in** a new place.
>   She **moved in** her new studio.
>   *she danced in her new studio*

means to make movement within an area.

> To **move in to** a new place.
>   We **moved in to** a new home.
>
> To move **into** a new place.
>   Let's move **into** the house, it's about to rain.

is to change location and move inside an enclosed space.
"Move in" also has the meaning "to get closer".

> We **moved in** to have a better look.